# Unzip file - Which is better Windows Web App or Windows VIrtual machine

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I have an web api application which is currently hosted on Windows azure web app. Now the application user can upload zip file and what we want to do, is unzip the file and use the inner files(we are uploading the zip to azure storage). The problem is I can't unzip on storage(since we can't execute any file on storage).

My concern now is whether I should redeploy my app on Virtual machine on Azure, so that I can unzip it on a local drive and then upload to the storage. Another question would be, whether I can do the same on the Azure Web App.

Comment: There are libraries for compression that you can use, just point it to the file and you don't execute anything, you just decompress and create the resulting files.

Comment: Thanks MiltoBeyond for the response. Azure storage is a flat storage and hence decompress function would cause issues since the zip can have sub-directories which cannot be created on azure storage. I will surely look into the decompress libraries, but I think I won't be so straight forward. Any more guidance on the same would be helpful.

Comment: If it is flat, you just emulate directory storage.  In fact one php library mentioned it. Flysystem.  Off the top of my head I can think of one way.  You have one file or a table in a database to hold the directory structure of a user, then hash the path, save the file with the hash as the filename and just store the reference to it.  To avoid collisions between users, you can name it `{user}.{hash}`, but the benefit is it will collide between files with the same path, so you will overwrite if a file exists.

Comment: This all can only be done once the decompression happens on zip. I think my original question stands till now. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You should be able to unzip and process in memory from azure storage.  How big are these files, and what type of processing do you need to do?

Comment: The user can upload SCORM Packages around 300MB to 500MB of data. Once unzip, I need a access a single file like the main file which would access all others files and folders in the same unzipped folder.

Comment: There are a few libraries that can help you decompress per file, but the zip itself holds the directory structure as meta information. So prior to unzipping you would process the directory information, create your emulated files and then put data into each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the library ***`SharpZipLib`*** it seems fairly straight forward. In fact I did little to their [extract example](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#-unpack-a-zip-with-full-control-over-the-operation) modify their code to do the emulation.

I just made this demo using NuGet to add the SharpZipLib library and did this little demo.  It outputs the resulting structure as a flat file called {zipfilename}.output which can be read and parsed fairly easily to find the file you need, or you can use a database, I just wanted to do this quickly.  You can even create a giant directory structure file for each user and parse and add to it as necessary.

### Example Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static MD5 hash = MD5.Create();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: TestApp.exe zipfilename [username] [password]");
                return;
            }

            string filename = args[0],
                   username = args.Length == 2 ? args[1] : "default",
                   password = args.Length == 3 ? args[2] : null;

            Dictionary<string, string> emulatedStructure = ExtractZipFile(filename, password, username);

            using(FileStream fs = File.Open(filename+".output",FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in emulatedStructure)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(pair.Key + "::>" + pair.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static byte[] CreateBinaryHash(byte[] original)
        {
            hash.Initialize();
            return hash.ComputeHash(original);
        }

        private static string CreateHash(string original, Encoding encoder = null)
        {
            if (encoder == null) encoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(original);
            data = CreateBinaryHash(data);
            return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", "");
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, string> ExtractZipFile(string archiveFilenameIn, string password, string UserName = "global")
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            ZipFile zf = null;
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(archiveFilenameIn);
                zf = new ZipFile(fs);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                {
                    zf.Password = password;     // AES encrypted entries are handled automatically
                }
                foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf)
                {
                    if (!zipEntry.IsFile)
                    {
                        continue;           // Ignore directories
                    }
                    string entryFileName = zipEntry.Name;
                    // to remove the folder from the entry:- entryFileName = Path.GetFileName(entryFileName);
                    // Optionally match entrynames against a selection list here to skip as desired.
                    // The unpacked length is available in the zipEntry.Size property.
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];     // 4K is optimum
                    Stream zipStream = zf.GetInputStream(zipEntry);

                    // Manipulate the output filename here as desired.
                    string fullZipToPath = UserName+"."+CreateHash(entryFileName)+".dat";

                    /* Since we have a flat structure... Don't do the following lines
                    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullZipToPath);
                    if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                    */

                    //Instead we add it to our dictionary which we can store wherever we want, just in case...
                    result.Add(entryFileName, fullZipToPath);

                    // Unzip file in buffered chunks. This is just as fast as unpacking to a buffer the full size
                    // of the file, but does not waste memory.
                    // The "using" will close the stream even if an exception occurs.
                    using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullZipToPath))
                    {
                        StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, streamWriter, buffer);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (zf != null)
                {
                    zf.IsStreamOwner = true; // Makes close also shut the underlying stream
                    zf.Close(); // Ensure we release resources
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

### Output in folder

Here is the resulting files in my debug folder using a zip I happened to have on hand:

[image: Example Files Created]

### Emulated Folder Structure

And within the output file you find entries like so:

```
EXAMPLES/BEER/BEER.ASM::>default.64FB4A2D08609091889912FF1C0AF95F.dat
EXAMPLES/BEER/BEER.EXE::>default.71C7A109E83F012C3E2EC2AC0E3E9AAC.dat
EXAMPLES/DDRAW/DDRAW.ASM::>default.77998184553594A98060D25C2CCC07CF.dat
EXAMPLES/DDRAW/DDRAW.EXE::>default.1AEA6C1F9A10E529659D78148A613362.dat
EXAMPLES/DDRAW/DDRAW.GIF::>default.891567CCBA5742B900C7EBA4D79EEA29.dat
EXAMPLES/DDRAW/DDRAW.INC::>default.70C19235197FE1FAF9BDAAB2C72CC324.dat
EXAMPLES/DDRAW/GIF87A.INC::>default.DCCFB6E469FFBF49BCF03146BE44678E.dat
EXAMPLES/DIALOG/DIALOG.ASM::>default.21A688565E9B4DA98FF306ACC7AB66CF.dat
EXAMPLES/DIALOG/DIALOG.EXE::>default.C5DFA20AA22E8007D4E0CF0128E51459.dat
EXAMPLES/DLL/ERRORMSG.ASM::>default.484A287050330B841576880A69C91148.dat
```

So you can get the right content for `EXAMPLES/DDRAW/DDRAW.ASM` and any other file that was inside the zip.

Comment: One thing to note you may want to put this code into a thread, an async process, or a scheduled task to not make the user wait while the entire zip file is processed.

Comment: @MiltxBeyond Thanks for the sample code. I think this would work. Just need to check if the relative paths of files in the main file can be accessed. Moreover I would just not store the files as .dat file. I would need to modify the code a bit, to store the actual file since they would be accessed publicly over web. This code example would really help me. Would mark the answer as correct once I get this code integrated.

Comment: I just used the dat files as an example.  The important part is the data.  In a web app you can have a get parameter say file name but you actually return the hashed file contents.  It may require some reworking of the links and the process by which the files call each other but it would solve your issue

Comment: This code really saved me and worked like a charm. Just had to tweak it a little bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this not as a zip-specific question, but as an Azure-specific question, namely about working with contents in blob storage (since that's where you stated you're placing your zip file after upload).

You are correct in that you can not perform any file operations (such as unzip) directly to a blob; it must be downloaded from storage to local disk (or memory stream) first.

As far as Web App vs Virtual Machine: That's strictly a matter of choice, as both have local disks which your app can get a path to.

As far as unzipping: The tool/library you use is totally up to you (can't recommend one here), and will all work with your local (writeable) disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on an Azure Web App without having to redeploy your app to a VM.  An [Azure Web Job](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) running inside your app would be the easiest way to do this.

One way to implement this would be to save all uploaded zip files to a folder in your web app, then have the web job regularly check that folder to see if there are any zip files in there. If it finds one, then unzip that file and upload the contents to blob storage.